# How to specify file format for powershell tee command?

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, tee

Using cmd.exe, I run `powershell ".\t.bat 2>&1 | tee results.txt"` on a Windows 10 laptop, and the resulting file `results.txt` comes out in "UCS-2 LE BOM" format according to Notepad++. Which my VBScript and others have trouble reading.

Yes, I can use "Encoding --> Encode In ASCII" or such, but that's a manual intervention, which I would like to automate the process.

Is there some PowerShell option that will allow me to say what format the tee output file should be?
Or some PowerShell/DOS command that would "fix"/change the file format for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [`Tee-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet (whose built-in alias on Windows is `tee`<sup>[1]</sup>) doesn't have an `-Encoding` parameter as of PowerShell 7.1  - unlike other cmdlets that write to files.

[GitHub suggestion #11104](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11104) suggests adding one.

`Tee-Object`'s default encoding in *Windows PowerShell*,  is "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) (which, strictly speaking is *not* the same as UCS-2 LE<sup>[2]</sup>), whereas in *PowerShell [Core] v6+*, where all cmdlets use the same encoding, it is BOM-less UTF-8.

It isn't officially documented, but you can *indirectly* control `Tee-Object`'s output encoding by assigning an encoding to `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding']`, but note that doing so also changes the default character encoding for `Out-File` and thereby also for `>` / `>>`.

The following command makes `Tee-Object` use UTF-8 encoding with a BOM:

```
powershell -c "$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'; .\t.bat 2>&1 | tee results.txt"
```

In both PowerShell editions, any value you can pass to `Out-File -Encoding` can be assigned to `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding']`, which in *Windows PowerShell* is limited to predefined enumeration values, whereas in *PowerShell [Core] v6+* (whose executable is `pwsh` rather than `powershell.exe`) you can additionally pass any instance derived from type [`System.Text.Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.Encoding).

---

<sup>[1] This alias is *not* defined on Unix-like platforms, so as not to shadow the native `tee` utility there.</sup>

<sup>[2] UCS-2 is an obsolete *fixed*-width encoding, where every character takes up exactly 2 bytes. UTF-16 is a _variable_width *superset* of that encoding that is additionally capable of encoding Unicode characters beyond the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane), via *pairs* of two-byte sequences called *surrogate pairs*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use Out-File instead.

Copy-pasted directly from the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7

> Notes
>
> You can also use the Out-File cmdlet or the redirection operator, both
> of which save the output in a file but do not send it down the
> pipeline.
>
> Beginning in PowerShell 6, Tee-Object uses BOM-less UTF-8 encoding
> when it writes to files. If you need a different encoding, use the
> Out-File cmdlet with the Encoding parameter.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.